# How do i loop within a loop in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I want my loop to count from 1 to 10 and then print to the document 1,2 and so on.

I tried to nest a while loop within a for loop but it counts from 1 to 10 and then prints out 10 results

```
for (var i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
  var j=0;
  while(j <=10){
    document.write('<br>Number '+j);
  j++
  }
}
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what you want. You only want to print 1 to 10 once? If so why do you use a nested loop in the first place?

Comment: no i want to count to 10 and then print 1, then count to 10 then print 2 etc etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var j=0;for (var i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
 
  while(j <=10){
 
  //
  var g=0;for (var i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
 
  while(g <=10){
    document.write('<br>Number '+g);
  g++
  }
}
  //
    document.write('<br>Page '+j);
  j++
   
  }
}
```

you're reseting j, remove the  `var j=0;`and insert a loop in the loop, first loop the page then the count.

Comment: You have some extra loops in this that you don't need.

Comment: actually i want it the other way around i want to first count to 10 and then print 1,2 etc

Comment: try to figure it out let me know where you get stuck.